# Move odd and even numbers in list to odd and even positions

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have a list with an equal number of odd and even integers. The goal is to modify the list to have odd integers at odd indices and even integers at the even indices.

Here is my approach:

I find out the numbers at even indexes and odd indexes. Then find out odd numbers at even indexes and even numbers at odd indexes. Finally swap the misplaced numbers.

```
x = [3, 2, 5, 6, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
even_pos = []
odd_pos = []
for i in range(len(x)):
    if x[i] % 2 == 0:
        even_pos.append(i)
    else:
        odd_pos.append(i)

even_pos_with_odd = []
odd_pos_with_even = []

for j in range(len(even_pos)):
    if even_pos[j] % 2 != 0:
        even_pos_with_odd.append(j)
    if odd_pos[j] % 2 == 0:
        odd_pos_with_even.append(j)

for n in range(len(even_pos_with_odd)):
    temp =  x[odd_pos[odd_pos_with_even[n]]]
    x[odd_pos[odd_pos_with_even[n]]] = x[even_pos[even_pos_with_odd[n]]]
    x[even_pos[even_pos_with_odd[n]]] = temp
```

I am not very happy with the solution though it works. Is there any better efficient solution to my problem? My aim was to make `x[]` like `[2, 3, 6, 5, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]` possibly sorted in the same odd-even format.

Comment: Really? z = [19, 11, 23, 16, 18, 20]  z.sort() -> [11, 16, 18, 19, 20, 23]  It did not work even though I had 3 odd and 3 even in it. If based on this logic I was given -1, I think it is not justified. Besides, 1st element at 0 index, I want to treat as even position and 2nd element at 1 index will be treated as odd position and so on!

Comment: Good point; your sample was simpler, for which it'd have worked. :-)

Comment: I did not say in the problem statement that integers would be contiguous.  x.sort() would work if the integers comes from contiguous/adjacent block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a *copy* of the list (solely to create new list of equal length), then use two counters to track where to insert even and odd numbers into the new list, incrementing the indices by 2 each time:

```
def odd_even_sieve(x):
    output = x[:]
    even_index, odd_index = 0, 1
    for value in x:
        if value % 2 == 0:
            output[even_index] = value
            even_index += 2
        else:
            output[odd_index] = value
            odd_index += 2
    return output
```

This is far simpler than trying to swap everything in-place.

Demo:

```
>>> def odd_even_sieve(x):
...     output = x[:]
...     even_index, odd_index = 0, 1
...     for value in x:
...         if value % 2 == 0:
...             output[even_index] = value
...             even_index += 2
...         else:
...             output[odd_index] = value
...             odd_index += 2
...     return output
... 
>>> odd_even_sieve([3, 2, 5, 6, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11])
[2, 3, 6, 5, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
>>> odd_even_sieve([19, 11, 23, 16, 18, 20])
[16, 19, 18, 11, 20, 23]
```

For sorted output (with odds and evens sorted independently), just sort the input:

```
>>> odd_even_sieve(sorted([3, 2, 5, 6, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]))
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
>>> odd_even_sieve(sorted([19, 11, 23, 16, 18, 20]))
[16, 11, 18, 19, 20, 23]
```

Comment: How the list can be sorted keeping its odd and even position intact?

Comment: @juggernaut: sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by the list being sorted. You could sort `x` when sieving, if that's what you mean: `for value in sorted(x):` to produce sorted output but with the odds and evens in sort order.

Comment: What I mean was, for example, x = [2, 3, 6, 5, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11] I wanted, 4 to appear before 6. For this example, x.sort() will work. If I had 1 instead of 11, 1 would become the 1st element in the list, whereas I wanted 2 as 1st element.

Comment: @juggernaut: just sort the input before passing it to the sieve as the answer says. The sieve function will make sure that `2` comes before `1` (if all items are positive) -- the first position has even index (`0`).

Comment: I implemented this code in C and it works like a charm! Much better than in-place swapping.In case of swapping technique if more even numbers are input than odd num then output will be wrong. But in this case odd positions are filled with zero(I used calloc).

Answer (score 2):

To move all even items to even indices and all odd items to odd indices inplace in `O(n**2)` time:

```
def fix_odd_even_indices(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        j = i
        while i & 1 != lst[i] & 1: # element is in the wrong place
            j += 1
            lst[i], lst[j] = lst[j], lst[i] # swap
```

The code may raise `IndexError` if the number of odds and evens is unequal.

Example:

```
lst = [3, 2, 5, 6, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
fix_odd_even_indices(lst)
print(lst)
# -> [2, 3, 6, 5, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

---

Here's a linear solution that returns a copy:

```
def fixed_odd_even_indices(seq):
    L = [None]*len(seq)
    L[1::2] = [x for x in seq if x & 1] # odd
    L[::2] = [x for x in seq if not x & 1] # even
    return L
```

Example:

```
print(fixed_odd_even_indices([3, 2, 5, 6, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]))
# -> [2, 3, 6, 5, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

Here's a linear single-pass solution that returns a copy (it is probably slower than the previous solution):

```
def fixed_odd_even_indices(iterable):
    odds, evens = [], []
    for x in iterable:
        (odds if x & 1 else evens).append(x)
    return [x for pair in zip(evens, odds) for x in pair]
```

Example:

```
L = fixed_odd_even_indices(map(int, sys.stdin)) # input one integer per line
```

Comment: Perhaps the linear solution may be faster even though it requires two passes, which should be avoided. Would have to check timings though, don't think it would be

Comment: @jamylak: for large `n` linear solution should "win" over the first quadratic solution. I've added a single-pass solution that calls the predicate only once (it is unlikely that it would be faster for any input).

Comment: I realised i forgot to mention, i meant the linear solution with 2 passes may be faster than the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

```
def odd_even(x):
    odds = sorted(filter(lambda n: n % 2 == 1, x))
    evens = sorted(filter(lambda n: n % 2 == 0, x))
    pairList = zip(odds, evens)
    return [n for t in pairList for n in t]
```

Answer (score 1):

[`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) version of the solution by @MartijnPieters

```
>>> from itertools import count
>>> x = [3, 2, 5, 6, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
>>> def odd_even_sieve(x):
        output = x[:]
        a, b = count(0, 2), count(1, 2)
        for value in x:
            output[next(a if value % 2 == 0 else b)] = value
        return output

>>> odd_even_sieve(x)
[2, 3, 6, 5, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

Answer (score 0):

Though you have chosen your answer, but I'd like to submit my way. Hope you may like it.

```
# Using python  2.7

First_list = [1,3,5,7,2,4,6,8]   #equal no. of even and odd numbers

temp_odd = [x for x in First_list if x%2 ==1]
temp_even = [x for x in First_list if x%2 ==0]

First_list[0::2] = temp_even    # as we know,0 is even index,followed by 2,4...
First_list[1::2] = temp_odd     # similarly starting with index 1, odd indices 
                                # are 3,5 ...
                                # we can write sorted(temp_odd) like that

print First_list
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone is looking for a function to flip the odd and even indices of an array, he/she can use this one:

```
import numpy as np
def flip(x):
        '''x must be an array'''
        flipped=[]
        for i in range(int(len(x)/2)):
                flipped.append(x[(i+1)*2-1])
                flipped.append(x[i*2])
        flipped=np.array(flipped)
        return flipped
>>> print(x)
[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19]
>>> print(flip(x))
[ 1  0  3  2  5  4  7  6  9  8 11 10 13 12 15 14 17 16 19 18]
```